# Resharper Policy - how to recommend var conditionally?

Tags: c#, resharper, var, policy

I want to create a custom policy for Resharper so that it recommends 'var' iff the actual type is specified on the right hand side of '=' immediately after the 'new' keyword, and to disable the recommendation to use 'var' otherwise.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a custom rule for that, there's already an option in  `ReSharper 9`. I cannot confirm it's there for the previous versions.

You can find it by going to the `ReSharper` tab, select `Options...`, and in the pop-up go to `Code Editing`, `C#` and finally `Code Style`.

Change the options for the first section from `Use 'var'` to `Use 'var' when evident`.

[image: ReSharper var option]

This results in the following:

[image: Conditionnal var option recommendation]

Comment: Looks like this was added in R#9 as the option is missing from R#8.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two different type of notifications:

[image: notifications]

The first one is a *suggestion*, the second one is a *hint*.

So you can simply click on the (second in this case) notification to show the bulb:

[image: bulb]

Then select *"Do not show"*. It won't affect the other suggestion.

[image: options]

You can save to the settings layer you want after that.

Comment: Would you mind indicating which version of R# you are using? Hopefully this is a solution that works for R#8, though I'd prefer to do it in a way that sets a global setting added to the git commit so other team members pick up the policy as well (then no squabbling in code reviews, set the policy and done)

Comment: @Kieran I made these screenshots with R# 8. If you want to store it in team-shared settings, it's possible to do so. After you click on *Configure inspection severity*, you'll get a dialog box with a *Save To* button that lets you choose the settings layer you want. I'll post a screenshot later from a different computer, because right now I'm on R# 9.